# extract an array into multiple comma separated variables

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array `$vars = [$a, $b, $c]`

I want to use it in `list()`, What I do is `list($a, $b, $c)` manually

What I want to know is If there a function to just extract it automatically from the `$vars` instead of doing it manually
so instead of

```
$vars = [$a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h, $i, $j, $k];
list($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h, $i, $j, $k);
```

i just write something like this

```
list(extraction($vars)) = ~~~
```

Because `$vars` is used in multiple occasions with different count of variables in it, Some times `3` like here, Sometimes `20` or more.

Comment: just use `$vars[$This]`

Comment: @rtfm the `$vars` values aren't limited to a specific number, I want to make it dynamically generated.

Comment: sorry im not following this at all

Comment: @rtfm `$vars` here has `count` of `2 vars`, In my code it is not static, people can add more vars into it, So i want to make it extract the variables automatically.

Comment: they are all ready variables, its an array, a standard variable type. there should be no need to change that

Comment: implode(",",$vars);

Comment: @Herco tried it, It outputs it as a single string and not a variable which doesn't work in `list()`

Comment: Your first line of code in the question already defines `$This` and `$That` variables, why would you need to get them again?

Comment: The arbitrary use of `$This, $That, $Those, $Idk...` should say it all, where are you defining these? If you want variables from values you need to make an associative array, and then you can use extract()

Comment: @trincot the `$This` and `$That` are static here, But then users can add aditional variables by themselves after it, So i just get it all at once.

Comment: If you don't know the names of the variables beforehand, how do you intend to use them in the code that follows later?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone not to define, But just taking `[$a, $b, $c]` and transforming it into `$a, $b, $c`. for the `list()`

Comment: @trincot will update the question now for better clairfication.

Comment: The best is to provide an example with input and desired output. And what the issue is for you to produce that output.

Comment: @trincot Is it better now?

Comment: What you ask for is really what `$_GET` and `$_POST` are already providing. I don't get it. Please provide a very concrete example, with actual values (with no doubt about their data type), ...

Comment: @trincot I really don't know how to explain it more, I just want to make the process of writing each `var` dynamic, instead of writing it one by one inside the `list()` Since they already exist in the array, Just want to know if that possible or not.

Comment: my last attempt, what's the real input? what's the real desired output? **not** what php functions you think you may want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without naming a value you can't simply define it back into local variable table.

For example:

```
$vars = [1];
```

Cannot become `$This = 1;`

You would need to do:

```
$vars = ['This' => 1];
```

Here is an example of how you can group `compact()` variables which you later want to `extract()`:

```
<?php

$This = 1;
$That = 2;
$Bla = 3;
$Foo = 4;
$Bar = 5;

$vars = ['This', 'That', 'Bla', 'Foo', 'Bar'];

$vars = compact(...$vars);

/*
Array
(
    [This] => 1
    [That] => 2
    [Bla] => 3
    [Foo] => 4
    [Bar] => 5
)
*/

$vars = extract($vars);

/*
$This = 1;
$That = 2;
$Bla = 3;
$Foo = 4;
$Bar = 5;
*/
```

Comment: Not sure why you want to do this anyway :/

Comment: How do i explain it, I was just asking if it is possible to pull the variables from `[$a, $b, $c]` out of its `[]`to be a plain three variables `$a, $b, $c` then i define it to a variable like `$list = ($a, $b, $c);`, Then i just use `list($list);`, Something like The reverse of `array_push($vars, $a, $b, $c)`; Is your method here only works with associative arrays?

Comment: I said you cant.. For the same reason $0, $1, $2 does not work. You need to name them.

Comment: @Toleo: No. That's a fundamental misunderstanding of how variables work. Once you assigned `[$a,$b,…]` - it has become an **array of values**, not an array of variables. Neither list/array remembers any variable names it was populated from. Once any expression is evaluated, it's a value. There's no going back and inferring its origins.

Comment: @mario Oh, I see, So `vars -> array` is easy, but `array -> vars` is hard, Or it is just doesn't exist in PHP? In both ways, The answer solves it a bit.

Comment: This is not the answer (and should not have been accepted), with all due respect to the poster, the OP has just realised his approach is wrong, classic XY question.

Answer (score 2):

Straw clutching here.

Essentially in the following; 'foo', 'bar' and 'baz' values are mapped to the variables $a, $b and $c.

```
<?php

function some_func() {
    $vals = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

    $idxs = array_slice(range('a', 'z'), 0, count($vals));
    $vals = array_combine($idxs, $vals);

    extract($vals);
    unset($vals, $idxs);

    var_export(get_defined_vars());
}

some_func();
```

Output:

```
array (
  'a' => 'foo',
  'b' => 'bar',
  'c' => 'baz',
)
```

The function some_func is used to reduce the output of get_defined_vars (reduced scope), to show the mapped variables.

However this feels like a Php anti-pattern.  You are best to stick to an array with keys.